# C# Sort List of X,Y Coordinates Clockwise

Tags: c#, sorting, coordinates

I am using .NET 2.0 so I don't have access to the nifty Linq; however, I have worked up some code that sorts a list of points clockwise/counterclockwise.

My problem is that the sort works perfectly fine if the list is not already sorted, but if for some reason the list is already sorted the sort function fails miserably.

I was wandering if someone could help point me in the right direction as to why this may be the cause.

Here is my call to the sort:

```
positions.Sort(new Comparison<Position>(MapUtils.SortCornersClockwise));
```

And here is the SortCornersClockwise function:

```
public static int SortCornersClockwise( Position A, Position B)
    {
        //  Variables to Store the atans
        double aTanA, aTanB;

        //  Reference Point
        Pixels reference = Program.main.reference;

        //  Fetch the atans
        aTanA = Math.Atan2(A.Pixel.Y - reference.Y, A.Pixel.X - reference.X);
        aTanB = Math.Atan2(B.Pixel.Y - reference.Y, B.Pixel.X - reference.X);

        //  Determine next point in Clockwise rotation
        if (aTanA < aTanB) return -1;
        else if (aTanB > aTanA) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
```

Where my reference is the point from which I determine the respective angle to each point in my list of points.

Now say I have a list of points:

```
15778066, 27738237
15778169, 27738296
15778185, 27738269
15778082, 27738210
```

These are already sorted in the correct order but calling the sort function yields:

```
15778082, 27738210
15778066, 27738237
15778185, 27738269
15778169, 27738296
```

Now take another set of sample points:

```
15778180, 27738255
15778081, 27738192
15778064, 27738219
15778163, 27738282
```

This list is not already in the correct order and calling the sort function yields:

```
15778064, 27738219
15778081, 27738192
15778180, 27738255
15778163, 27738282
```

Which is sorted correctly.  This pattern repeats it self for each set of coordinates that are already sorted and for those that aren't.  Any ideas?

Comment: You really should pass your reference point into the method instead of referencing (no pun intended) a 'global' variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (aTanA < aTanB) return -1;
else if (aTanB > aTanA) return 1;
```

These two conditions are the same! *Either* swap the variables *or* turn around the inequality sign, but not both.

Comment: Now I feel stupid, I was playing with that function and typed that line out wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent observation that Henning made, you may also be surprised by the output once you fix that problem.

The circular symmetry makes this a somewhat unusual sorting algorithm when compared with normal sorts on totally ordered domains. Since there is circular symmetry, there are n valid clockwise orderings, given n points and it may matter to you which of those orderings you prefer.

As it stands, use of atan2 unmodified will result in a cut-line with coordinates (x,0) where x<0.

Consider coordinates A = (-10, 1) and B = (-10, -1), measured relative to the reference. You probably imagine that A should appear before B in the result, but in fact it will be the other way around since atan2 returns just less than π for A, but just more than -π for B.

If you want a cut-line with coordinates (x,0) where x>0 simply add 2π to any negative values returned from atan2.

Comment: Excellent observation. I had noticed this same occurrence where 2 (or more) points were on the -X plane. Great tip on the solution ... I was about to embark on something much more difficult if (X == ref.X).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
else if(aTanA > aTanB) return 1;
```

Not sure if that would cause your issue though.